# Communicate between Next JS Web and Native Mobile App

Tags: next.js, webview, webkit, native, app-router

I'm having a web server by Next JS (BE by Spring), and iOS, Android App. I'm handling change page in Web, and i want Native apps to detect this for handle some logic in apps.
I tried to use window.webkit.messageHandlers but it return Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "messageHandlers").

How can i solve this, or any other solutions ?

Here's my code:

```
if (data == 200) {
  window.webkit.messageHandlers.testApp.postMessage.bind("OK");
}
```

Comment: data == 200 means change page success on Web